# Python requests to scrape from Android Device Manager https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, google-plus, google-latitude

With a little clue about Python I am trying to get location data from [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) utilizing [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests).  I am trying to show a JSON location feed from Android devices in the same manner [pyiCloud](https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud) does with Apple devices.

As pr now.  I have not gotten any further than the simple:

```
import time, requests
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager', auth=(GoogleUsername, GooglePassword ))

f = open('dump.html', 'w+')
tmst = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
f.write(tmst + '<br>')
f.write(r.text)
f.close
```

Giving me the login screen.  Anyone?

---

My intentions is to get live location data from my android devices without installing any app or similar on the device itself.  Simply by scraping data either from Android Device Manager, or perhaps this could be solved by [Google+ Location Sharing](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2998354?hl=en)?

Comment: Your authentication method is probably not supported. What you are attempting to do is probably not allowed by google's terms of use.